# 1-dimensional Matrix is changed to a vector in R

Tags: r, vector, matrix, rcpp

```
> a<-matrix(c(1:9),3,3)
> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
> a[3,]*a[,3]  # I expect 1x1 matrix as result of this.
[1] 21 48 81
> class(a)
[1] "matrix"
> class(a[3,])
[1] "integer"
```

In R, 1-dimensional matrix is changed to a vector. Can I avoid this?
I would like to keep 1-D matrix as a matrix. Actually, I need to throw many kind of matrix to RcppArmadillo, even zero-D matrix. Changing matrix to vector by itself is my problem.

Comment: `class(a[3,])` only tells you the storage mode. You probably should be using str() since it would tell you the `length`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is an R [FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-my-matrices-lose-dimensions_003f). You need to do `a[3,,drop = FALSE]`.

Answer (score 9):

You're confusing element-by-element multiplication and matrix multiplication (see `?"*"`).  You want `%*%`:

```
> a[3,]%*%a[,3]
     [,1]
[1,]  150
```