# how to get each column as data.frame (instead of a vector) from a data.frame?

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

Normally when you get a column, it is a vector. How can I keep it as the data.frame with the same row names and corresponding column name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [1-dimensional Matrix is changed to a vector in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949202/1-dimensional-matrix-is-changed-to-a-vector-in-r)

Comment: @joran Sorry didn't see the possible duplicate.  I'll leave my response and if this question is closed removal of my answer is a moot point.

Comment: @TylerRinker Don't worry about it. This is just a really common question, that's all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of calling the desired column with a comma i.e. data.frame[,i] use data.frame[i] to preserve the class as data.frame and also retain row names.

```
data.frame[,i] #As a vector
data.frame[i] #As a data.frame
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could do that +1

Comment: I guess that adds some value to my question post and deserve not to be closed :)

Answer (score 6):

use the argument drop = FALSE as in:

```
mtcars[, 1, drop = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a single number when subsetting a data.frame, you get a one-column data.frame.  This is different than matrix subsetting, which requires a "missing" `i` argument to return the entire column (which it then converts to a vector).

```
# mtcars is a data.frame
mtcars[1]       # first column
str(mtcars[1])  # is still a data.frame
# 'data.frame':   32 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ mpg: num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
# MTCARS is a matrix
MTCARS <- as.matrix(mtcars)
as.matrix(MTCARS)[1]        # only the first element
# [1] 21
str(as.matrix(MTCARS)[,1])  # the first column, as a vector
 Named num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:32] "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" ...
```