# R avoid coercion from matrix to numeric

Tags: r, type-coercion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [1-dimensional Matrix is changed to a vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949202/1-dimensional-matrix-is-changed-to-a-vector-in-r)

I work with `matrix` objects in R and many times it happens that I want to select only one column of a matrix a use it as a `matrix` of one column !!! Yes, I mean I don't want R to coerce it automatically to a `numeric` class because the meaning is a matrix of 1 column in that case. How to avoid R doing this silly conversion all the time at a general level. I don't want to clutter my code with `as.matrix` everywhere !

Comment: Sounds a like a read of the R Inferno is in order: http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf  You're currently in Circle 8.1.44.

Comment: @GSee: A quick search turned up: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9949202/892313, http://stackoverflow.com/q/12601692/892313, http://stackoverflow.com/q/7598674/892313. The first or the third would be the closest duplicate, I think.

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-November/218081.html

Comment: you guys are better than me at finding duplicate AND henceforth giving to me the answer. So, many thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `drop=FALSE`

```
> matrix(1:10, ncol=2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10
> matrix(1:10, ncol=2)[, 2]
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
> matrix(1:10, ncol=2)[, 2, drop=FALSE]
     [,1]
[1,]    6
[2,]    7
[3,]    8
[4,]    9
[5,]   10
```